# Initialize property on first use

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm curious on what might be a better pattern for creating a property attribute that initialises its value on 1st use. Below is a class with several variations on a theme.

```py
def some_initializer(s):
    return f"Value: {s}"

class Foo(object):
    """ Initialize on first use properties """
    def __init__(self):
        self._prop1 = None

    @property
    def prop1(self):
        """ Existing private member attribute """
        if not self._prop1:
            self._prop1 = some_initializer("prop1")
        return self._prop1

    @property
    def prop2(self):
        """ Create private attribute on demand """
        if not hasattr(self, "_prop2"):
            self._prop2 = some_initializer("prop2")
        return self._prop2

    @property
    def prop3(self):
        """ Create private attribute on demand - shorter """
        self._prop3 = getattr(self, "_prop3", some_initializer("prop3"))
        return self._prop3

    @property
    def prop4(self):
        """ Stash value in attribute with same name as property """
        _prop4 = self.__dict__.get('_prop4')
        if _prop4 is not None:
            return _prop4
        self._prop4 = _prop4 = some_initializer("prop4")
        return _prop4

>> f = Foo()
>> print(f.prop1)
>> print(f.prop2)
>> print(f.prop3)
>> print(f.prop4)
Value: prop1
Value: prop2
Value: prop3
Value: prop4
```

In the past I've used variations prop1, prop2 and prop3. Recently I was introduced to the prop4 variation that I feel is quite confusing although perhaps technically correct. Any cons with these variations or maybe there are better ways?

Edit: Ideally, it would be nice to maintain compatibility with property setter and deleter decorators too.

Answer (score 2):

i would just write a custom descriptor and use that instead:

```
class cached_property:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance:
            return self

        res = instance.__dict__[self.f.__name__] = self.f(instance)
        return res
```

usage:

```
class C:
    @cached_property
    def prop(self):
        print('you will see me once')
        return 4
```

Comment: A nice approach - thanks. Might need a tiny bit more work to support setter and deleter decorators too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) to memoize the property value:

```
from functools import lru_cache

class Foo(object):

    @property
    @lru_cache()
    def prop(self):
        print("called once")
        return 42


foo = Foo()
print(foo.prop)
print(foo.prop)
```

Comment: lru_cache is very useful and it's easy to forget it works under a @property decorator - thanks. It would be nice to maintain support for setters and deleters too.

Comment: you could make this even easier by creating a function: `def cached_property(func): return property(lru_cache()(func))`

Answer (score 0):

I also thought of a descriptor but came up with this approach

```
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
def five():
    return 5
def six():
    return 6
def seven():
    return 7

class FirstInit:
    def __init__(self, initializer):
        self.initializer = initializer
        self.data = WeakKeyDictionary()
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        try:
            value = self.data[instance]
        except KeyError as e:
            value = self.initializer()
            self.data[instance] = value
        return self.data[instance]
```

Usage:

```
class F:
    a = FirstInit(five)
    b = FirstInit(six)
    c = FirstInit(seven)
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = f'{name}:{self.c}'

>>> f = F('foo')
>>> f.name
'foo:7'
>>> f.a, f.b
(5, 6)
>>> f.a = 'sixteen'
>>> f.a, f.b
('sixteen', 6)
>>> f.b += 13
>>> f.a, f.b
('sixteen', 19)
>>>
```

---

For an *initializer* that takes an argument:

```
d = {'P1':5, 'P2':6, 'P3':7}
def initializer(which):
    return d[which]

class FirstInit:
    def __init__(self, initializer, prop):
        self.initializer = initializer
        self.prop = prop
        self.data = WeakKeyDictionary()
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        try:
            value = self.data[instance]
        except KeyError as e:
            value = self.initializer(self.prop)
            self.data[instance] = value
        return self.data[instance]

class G:
    a = FirstInit(initializer, 'P1')
    b = FirstInit(initializer, 'P2')
    c = FirstInit(initializer, 'P3')
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = f'{name}:{self.c}'
```

...

```
>>> g = G('foo')
>>> g.name
'foo:7'
>>> g.b += 16
>>> g.a,g.b
(5, 22)
>>> g.a = 'four'
>>> g.a,g.b
('four', 22)
>>>
```